# Is search_after still beneficial when used along aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

The advantage of using `search_after` over `size` and `from` is that for deep pages the whole result set doesn't have to be loaded into memory.

[The docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html) say:

> Avoid using from and size to page too deeply or request too many results at once. Search requests usually span multiple shards. Each shard must load its requested hits and the hits for any previous pages into memory. For deep pages or large sets of results, these operations can significantly increase memory and CPU usage, resulting in degraded performance or node failures.

However, when I use `search_after` with bucket aggregation like this:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "search_after": [1611064800000,6609534],
  "sort": [
    {"date": "asc"},
    {"tie_breaker": "asc"}
  ],
  "aggs" : {
    "cities" : {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cityId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Elastic returns the same aggregation results regardless of the `search_after` value. That's correct. But then, how does it compute the buckets without loading the whole result set into memory?

Answer (score 0):

The Hits API is separated from the Aggregations API and `search_after` only applies to the `hits`.

Look into [Composite Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) if you need to optimize/paginate aggregation buckets.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to paginate the buckets. I wanted to know *how* Elastic computes the buckets without actually loading the documents in memory.